# S/PDIF audio not working

Tags: audio

I have been trying to get a PCIe sound card to work, analog works fine out of box, S/PDIF is recognized by Pavu but not Alsa Mixer, no TOS link light comes on, no sound ever leaves the line. How can I get S/PDIF audio working on Linux?

Comment: First step is to take Pulseaudio out of the equation and test on the Alsa level (which Pulseaudio uses). That there are no Alsa Mixer controls is irrelevant. Stop or suspend Pulseaudio, do `aplay -L` and see if there are any `IEC...` devices, find or make a WAV file with the correct bitrate, number of channels etc and try to use `aplay -D ...` to play it. Edit question as appropriate, in particular with the `IEC...` devices you find (or just some, if there's a lot due to configuration variations).